# Passing parameters from ISPF DSLIST to REXX script automatically

Tags: mainframe, rexx, ispf

If i have a normal ISPF screen like the one shown below
[image]

Now, I already have a rexx script that gives me the number of lines in a particular pds (just simply the number of lines, regardless of what's in those lines) Now I want to design a command in ispf, such that on entering that command (as depicted by the arrow in the image), that particular rexx script is automatically executed and the corresponding file name beside which the command is typed, is sent as input to my rexx script. I can even post the rexx script if needed, in case changes are to be made to it too.

Comment: Aplogies, I meant PS, not PDS

Comment: Hava a read on `sysproc` & `sysexec` dd's. `Sysproc` can hold clist & rexx while `sysexec` just holds rexx. Also look at `altlib` command, it allows you to add/remove pds to these two libs

Answer (score 4):

When you type any TSO command as a line command ISPF automatically passes the fully qualified data set as a parm (use PF1 from 3.4 and select 2 for TSO commands).  So just have the TSO command entered beside the dataset just use the SELECT CMD to invoke your REXX exec and pass whatever parms you want.  The first exec will have the DSN passed so it can easily pass that to your exec.